My pet caterpillars don't wanna eat
I know caterpillars aren't a normal pet to have but anyways here's my story:
On the first day, I found four tiny caterpillars waddling in my garden. I decided to take them and provide them with food and a comfy home, away from danger. Now two of them have already started the pupating process, meanwhile the other two are still waddling on the leaves I gave them.
But, today I found both of them not eating. It is NOT normal for my caterpillars to not eat because they've always eaten the leaves I gave. Now it's evening, they still haven't eaten a bit of the leaves. They are not starting their pupating process, neither are they preparing to molt. I decided to switch the container they were in with a new and bigger one. They still haven't eaten.
I know some of you might say maybe they have eaten a harmful substance, but no. I handled them extra careful, and stayed away from lotion and pesticides. And the soil I gave the caterpillars smells awful, not like always. I changed them, and for those of you who know a lot about caterpillars, please tell me what happened to them, so it won't be too late for me to handle whatever it is that did something to my caterpillars.
